# Is there an `else` for for comprehensions

Tags: python

I have the following code:

```
[mc.split('$', 1)[-1] for mc in marketCapsUnclean if 'B' in mc]
```

Which transforms something like:

```
['blabla $10M', 'blabla $10B']
```

into

```
['$10B']
```

I would like instead to get a value for the elements which don't pass the `if` test, like this:

```
['N/A', '$10B']
```

I would like to do something like:

```
[mc.split('$', 1)[-1] for mc in marketCapsUnclean if 'B' in mc else 'N/A']
```

But this is not legal syntax.

So is there a way to achieve something similar with a for comprehension?

Comment: No, because the `if` is a *filter*. Include this item or don't include it, a boolean choice.

Comment: You are not filtering. You are producing different values for each item, so you want to use a *conditional expression* in the value expression. `[mc.split('$', 1)[-1] if 'B' in mc else 'N/A' for mc in marketCapsUnclean]`. See the duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the `else` condition with value after the `if` before the looping structure:

```
[mc.split('$', 1)[-1] if 'B' in mc else 'N/A' for mc in marketCapsUnclean ]
```